# Block User Agent with iptables not working

Tags: user-agent, iptables

I am getting relentless requests on one of my domains which I believe is coming from the Pushdo virus (or similar) see log snippet below. Apparently it picks random domains to send traffic to in order to mask the requests to it's command node. I have tried Fail2Ban but the IPs keep changing constantly and was banning 50K+ and the banning was using more resources than the requests. I was hoping to take care of the HTTP requests (there are SMTP one too but that is another question!) by blocking the user agent.

I have tried using

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --algo bm --string "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)" -j DROP
```

But this does not work! What am I doing wrong? Also, any other suggestions for dealing with this - it has been going on for over a month now and I am pulling my hair out!

OS: CentOS 6.4

Log Snippet:

```
121.54.54.47 - - [20/Oct/2013:03:32:37 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 14772 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
125.60.156.224 - - [20/Oct/2013:03:32:37 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 14772 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
84.108.50.80 - - [20/Oct/2013:03:32:37 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 14772 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
110.143.55.42 - - [20/Oct/2013:03:32:37 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 14772 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
122.208.75.75 - - [20/Oct/2013:03:32:37 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 14772 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
1.2.248.56 - - [20/Oct/2013:03:32:38 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 14772 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
180.194.171.167 - - [20/Oct/2013:03:32:38 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 14772 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
190.200.59.125 - - [20/Oct/2013:03:32:39 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 14772 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
223.197.238.249 - - [20/Oct/2013:03:32:40 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 14772 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
200.121.4.163 - - [20/Oct/2013:03:32:39 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 14772 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using -A which appends the rule to your existing set, so it's probably not doing anything. Using -I would probably work, but you likely want to script this and get it put in the right order.